# IE8: Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am getting an error `Expected identifier, string or number` in IE8 `referring to line 17 character 21` of the following code:

```
define(
    [
        "underscore"
    ,   "Backbone"
    ,   "text!assetListingTemplate"
    ]
,   function(_, Backbone, template) {
        "use strict";

        var tmpl = _.template(template);
        var AssetListing = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: "li"

        ,   attributes: function() {
                return {
                    id: this.model.cid
                ,   class: this.model.get("type")
                };
            }

        ,   render: function() {
                this.el.innerHTML = tmpl(this.model.attributes);
                return this.el;
            }
        });

        return AssetListing;
    }
);
```

Which is:

```
,   class: this.model.get("type")
```

This error is usually due to a trailing coma in an `Object` or similar minor formatting issues that IE does not handle gracefully. Perhaps I have been staring at code for too long but I can't see any such issues here, I have even [JSLinted](http://www.jslint.com/) it and it failed to find any issues except for not agreeing with my style.

The error is not `this.model` either as it still occurs if I replace all instances of it for regular strings.

Can any eagle eyes spot what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't like `class` since class is a [future reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) as define in ECMAScript2

Put `class` in quotes `"class"`

```
attributes: function() {
                return {
                    id: this.model.cid
                ,   "class": this.model.get("type")
                };
            }
```

Comment: Ah I see a reserved word... could of been at this all day thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Glad I could help! And I have spent all day on this one before!